# C# Windows From add/remove list

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to add a "slushbucket" (ServiceNow term) to a C# Windows Form, like the image below, but can't figure out what they're actually called so therefore can't look into how they're created.

Does anyone know what they're called, or better yet how to implement one into a windows form?

I need it to list values from Table1 on the left, then when they are added to the right hand list and the save button is clicked, the values are written to Table2. It would also need to show existing values for Table2 if there are any.

[image: SlushBucket]

Comment: Just code this yourself using two ListBoxes or two ListViews and some Buttons.

Comment: Create a new form, add 2 listboxs to it and the add and remove button. Try to do some coding (fill the left listbox,...) and if you have a concrete question you can ask here again.

Comment: Its extremely trivial to write, the button handlers just take the selected values from the box and add them to the other side

Comment: Well, you've got the prototype already. Should be easy to drop those controls on a form, click a couple of times to wire up the event handlers, and write code to add/remove items. We aren't going to write it for you.

Comment: take a look at http://www.dotnetperls.com/listbox

Comment: Suggestion, there is no reason to learn Windows Forms, mvoe away, it's a nearly dead technology, move to wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is how the form looks like:
[Form1.Png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxDgY.png)
Here is a simple code that implements your idea as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 6; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("item" + i);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {             
            listBox2.Items.Add("item" + i);
        }
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {` 

        if (listBox2.Items.Count >0)
        {
            string message = "";
            foreach (var item in listBox2.Items)
            {
                message += item + "\n";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }`
        /// write here the code that save listbox1 and listbox2 items
        /// to a text file or a database table and load this text file or 
        /// the database table inside these two listboxes you could write the 
        /// code that load data to the two list boxes in the constructor instead
        /// of the tow for loops thats i've provided.
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!listBox2.Items.Contains(listBox1.SelectedItem))
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);
                listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item already exists");
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing selected to add");

        }         
    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(listBox2.SelectedItem))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(listBox2.SelectedItem);
                listBox2.Items.Remove(listBox2.SelectedItem);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item already exists");
            }

        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException exc)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Nothing selected to remove");
        }

    }
}
```

hope that's what you were looking for :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the image output :

[image]

and your code is below. I hope this will be helpful for you.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ArrayList Table1;
    ArrayList Table2;
    bool isSaved = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Table1 = new ArrayList();
        Table2 = new ArrayList();

        Table1.Add("Value1");
        Table1.Add("Value2");
        Table1.Add("Value3");
        Table1.Add("Value4");
        Table1.Add("Value5");           
    }
    private void populateListBox1() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Table1.Count;i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(Table1[i]);
        }
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        populateListBox1();          
    }
    private void refreshListBox1() {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        populateListBox1();  
    }
    private void addToRight() {
        try
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(Table1[listBox1.SelectedIndex]);
            Table1.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
        }
        catch 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have to select an item first !");
        }

        refreshListBox1();
    }
    private void removeFromRight(){
        if (isSaved)
        {
            try
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(Table2[listBox2.SelectedIndex]);
                Table1.Add(Table2[listBox2.SelectedIndex]);
                isSaved = false;
            }
            catch 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have to select an item first !");
                isSaved = true;
            }
            try
            {
                Table2.RemoveAt(listBox2.SelectedIndex);
                listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(listBox2.SelectedIndex);
                isSaved = false;
            }
            catch 
            {
                if(listBox2.Items.Count==0)
                MessageBox.Show("This list is an empty list");
                isSaved = true;
            }

        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("You have to click save button first !");
        }

    }
    private void saveToTable2() {
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count;i++)
        {
            Table2.Add(listBox2.Items[i].ToString());
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Saved !");
        isSaved=true;           
    }
    private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addToRight();
    }

    private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveToTable2();           
    }

    private void btn_remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        removeFromRight();
    }
}
```

}